# Always have one selected DataGrid row

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm working with WPF dataGrind now and faced with an ussie. I need that dataGrid always has one selected row. Always and only one.

Is it possible?

Comment: This is possible, but what if there are no rows in the grid?

Comment: if there are some rows - what should be the initial value? should the first row be selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<DataGrid SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" PreviewMouseDown="PreviewMouseDown"/>
```

edit:

```
    private void PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: maybe you try to add a SelectionChanged eventhandler and set the SelectedItem to the RemovedItem when SelectedIndex = -1 or you supress ctrl+left in PreviewMouseDown?